# Make A kitten Follow me

Tags: cats, behavior, training

I have 2 1/2 months old male persian kitten , I bought it a month ago and the kitten does not seem to be friendly as I thought, sometimes it just get scared and keeps on running away. How much time it can take to over come this issue ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every cat has different personality. Moreover, the first 3 to 4 months are most important in building a cat's personality. If the cat has bad experience with humans in his earlier life, he will become suspicious of humans.

To gain the cat's confidence, progress gradually.

1. Give the cat a separate room. She might get afraid of new humans or other pets.
2. Give her some hiding area like long leafy plants or cardboard boxes, where the cat will feel secure.
3. Food is the most important thing to build trust. At first keep the food in tray and walk away. Then stay and watch him eating. Finally try feeding by hand.
4. Regularly bring new gifts and toys for the cat to play with.
5. Make a cat tree. Elevation generally gives them confidence.
6. Keep the litter box clean and in a safe place where the cat will not be afraid to go.
7. Slowly start stroking the cat softly.
8. Talk with your cat.
9. Try lifting up the cat over your chest and keep stroking.
10. Last but not the least try to make him socialized by introducing him to your family members and friends.